# Monomorphism/Isomorphism of $C_4$-tangent cones for complex varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Suppose that $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ is a reduced complex analytic space (or complex algebraic variety if you prefer). The tangent linear fiber space $TM$ associated to $M$ is defined as the analytic spectrum of the graded algebra $S^\bullet (\Omega^1_M)$. Any analytic morphism $\phi\colon M \to N$ between complex analytic spaces induces a tangent morphism $T\phi \colon TM\to \phi^*TN$. In particular, $\phi$ is an immersion if and only if $T\phi$ is a monomorphism of linear fiber spaces.

My question does not regard the tangent linear fiber space but the $C_4$-tangent cone $C_4M$. Recall, that $C_4M$ is the cone over $M$ defined as the analytic spectrum of the graded algebra $S^\bullet \left(\Omega^1_M\right) / \mathrm{Torsion} $. Geometrically, this cone is the closure of $TM_\mathrm{reg}$ inside the reduction of $TM$. For any morphism $\phi\colon M \to N$ of complex analytic spaces one once again obtains a morphism of cones $C_4\phi\colon C_4M\to \phi^*C_4N$. My question is now, are there any meaningful conclusions that can be drawn from $C_4\phi$ being a monomorphism or even an isomorphism? For example, if $C_4\phi$ is a monomorphism is $\phi$ still necessarily an immersion?

I am currently in a situation where I have an analytic homeomorphism $\nu$ of reduced complex analytic spaces such that $C_4\nu$ is a monomorphism and I would like to conclude that $\nu$ is an isomorphism itself. Are there any resources treating these kinds of questions?